# Python count records in List of Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dictionaries` with format something similar to:

```
complete_list = [{'id': 1, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'ggg'}, {'id': 2, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'hhh'}, {'id': 3, 'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'other': 'ggg'}]
```

and I wish to obtain unique records count based on `mobile`, something similar to:

```
[{'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'rec_count': 2}, {'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'rec_count': 1}]
```

I am trying the following code:

```
unique_list = list({v.get('mobile', ''): v for v in complete_list}.values())
```

With this code, I am able to get the Unique records `list`. But don't know how to get the count as well.

Can someone please explain how this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yet? What difficulties are you facing in your code? Please specify.

Comment: updated the question summary. Please have a look again.

Comment: Are entries with identical `mobile` values guaranteed to have identical `name` values?

Comment: @patrick-haugh I need all unique mobile records with their count. Other values doesn't matter much. But yes, you can assume the 'name' vallue would be identical for every identical 'mobile' value

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the number of times each `mobile` appears, the easiest way is probably with a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

complete_list = [{'id': 1, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'ggg'}, {'id': 2, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'hhh'}, {'id': 3, 'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'other': 'ggg'}]

mobile_count = Counter(i['mobile'] for i in complete_list)
print(mobiles)
```

prints

```
Counter({'2345': 2, '3456': 1})
```

`Counter`s are a special kind of `dict`.  Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `list` of mobiles and then `loop` through your `unique_list` to update the records as the following:

```
complete_list = [{'id': 1, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'ggg'},
                 {'id': 2, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'hhh'},
                 {'id': 3, 'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'other': 'ggg'}]
mobiles = [x['mobile'] for x in complete_list]
unique_list = list({v.get('mobile', ''): v for v in complete_list}.values())
for elem in unique_list:
    elem['rec_count'] = mobiles.count(elem['mobile'])
print unique_list
```

output:

```
[{'mobile': '2345', 'other': 'hhh', 'rec_count': 2, 'id': 2, 'name': 'ABC'}, {'mobile': '3456', 'other': 'ggg', 'rec_count': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'XYZ'}]
```

**EDIT**

A more optimized way of doing this is probably using two `for-loops` to update the `list` accordingly, or create a new `list`:

```
complete_list = [{'id': 1, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'ggg'},
                 {'id': 2, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'hhh'},
                 {'id': 3, 'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'other': 'ggg'}]
for i, v in enumerate(complete_list):
    rec_count = 1
    for j, v2 in enumerate(complete_list):
        if i != j and v['mobile'] == v2['mobile']:
            rec_count += 1
            del complete_list[j]
    v['rec_count'] = rec_count
print complete_list
```

output:

```
[{'mobile': '2345', 'other': 'ggg', 'rec_count': 2, 'id': 1, 'name': 'ABC'}, {'mobile': '3456', 'other': 'ggg', 'rec_count': 1, 'id': 3, 'name': 'XYZ'}]
```

If you want to create a new `list`, remove `del complete_list[j]` append the record to the new `list` at the end of the first `loop`

Comment: Is there any optimized way to solve this ? (This does solves the problem I am looking for)

Comment: How does it not solve the problem? Can you explain further please

Comment: Nevermind, I misread your comment. You mean you want a more optimized way of doing that?

Comment: @Naveen I just updated my answer and added a more optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the number of elements in unique_list with `len(unique_list)`. I believe this is the count of records you are looking for.

Another solution is to use a for loop and set math to count the number of unique mobile numbers without creating the list of unique records.

```
complete_list = [{'id': 1, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'ggg'},
                 {'id': 2, 'mobile': '2345', 'name': 'ABC', 'other': 'hhh'},
                 {'id': 3, 'mobile': '3456', 'name': 'XYZ', 'other': 'ggg'}]

mobile_numbers = set()
for record in complete_list:
  mobile_numbers.add(record['mobile'])
```